# How do I get the ubuntu developers to fix a bug?

Tags: bug-reporting

So, there is this bug, which is critical to our production systems ([#1246245](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/proftpd-dfsg/+bug/1246245) - proftpd fails to restart after logrotate). It makes ProFTPd terminate every few days and I have to restart it. Of course I can apply the patch manually on every production machine we are spinning up, but there should be a simpler way: Just patch it.

The bug is confirmed and has a (one-line!) patch since October 2013. But nobody wants to do it. I've commenting on the bug daily for a week now and even wrote a mail to the maintainer (which is the "ProFTPD Maintainance Team"). Fixing the bug should take 5 minutes. But nobody cares.

So my question is: *Given there is a bug, but nobody fixes it, how do I get the developers to do it?*

Comment: If I were in need of money, I'd offer to create and submit a patch for you for $20 or so. Too bad I am not...

Comment: While it really sounds unreasonable to bug open source developers to fix bugs, this is a question that should be asked. There are plenty of users who have to deal with bugs and features that render their previously useful systems much less useful. Few of us are actually good enough or have the time to fix the bugs ourselves. So, what's the point of downvoting this particular question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're a paying customer who is paying a service contract for 24/7 service, I'm not so sure if posting a message daily is something you should do or something you should be proud of.  The bug has gone unfixed for 3 years -- that's nothing; I've seen longer than that.  I've also see new software versions getting released that make old bug reports irrelevant (i.e., technically, the code is never fixed because the program is rewritten from the ground up).

Rather than posting here daily in the hope of getting some attention, here are some more constructive suggestions:

- The upstream site actually has source code in a git repository (http://www.proftpd.org/git.html).  Clone it from there, patch it yourself, and then run this instead of the Ubuntu package.
- Consider other ftp servers.  I see pure-ftpd, tftpd, vsftpd, etc.
- Move to a commercial-based operating system and/or ftp server.  Ubuntu and open-source is not for everyone.  Surely some "mission-critical" problems might use commercial software just so they can get service when they want it.

Actually, maybe ignore the first point.

I just noticed that the problem is in a script and not the program's source code.  Why can't you edit the script yourself?  Sure, it's inconvenient, but with the time you've already spent on it, I think you could have done it already...

(In the bug report, you said you don't have write access?  Nagging the people who can give you write access and/or patch the file is perhaps more productive than nagging anyone else.)

Comment: Canonical *does* provide paid support.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Yes they do.  But is the "paid support" along the lines of patching software or more like help with installation or setup?  At best, they will take a note of the problem and it will be added to the queue -- in a way, no different from reporting bugs.launchpad.net .  I'd be interested to hear of concrete examples of something different.

Comment: In the end, it is far easier to ask the system administrator to modify a script file -- especially given that the patch is known and tested by others...